# How do I read the first 5 lines in this column and skip to the nth line and read the next 5 lines again until I reach the end of the column data?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I am reading from a csv file using python and I pulled the data from one column. Every 15 lines is a set of data for one category but only the first 5 lines from that set is relevant. How can I read the first 5 lines of every 15 lines from a total of 205 lines? It reads every other 15 up to a point and then it begins to misalign. The blue rectangles shows where it starts to stray.Here is an image of my data format from the column :

[image]

```
  inp = pd.read_csv(input_dir)
win = inp['File '][1:]
ny4= inp['Unnamed: 24']
df = pd.DataFrame({"Ny/4" : ny4})
ny4_len = len(ny4)

#    
for i in win:
    itr.append(i.split('_'))


for e in itr:
        plh1.append(e[4:e.index("SFRP")])
plh1 = plh1[1::13]
win_df = pd.DataFrame({'Window' : plh1})

for u in win_df['Window']:
    plh2.append(k.join(u))

chicken = len(df)/12
#kow = list(islice(ny4,1, 17)    )

#  
maxm = pd.concat(list(map(lambda x: x[1:6], np.array_split(ny4,17))), ignore_index=True)
plh2_df= pd.DataFrame({'Window Name': plh2})
ny4_data= pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(maxm.values,(17,5)), columns = ['Center', 'UL', 'UR', 'LL','LR'])
conc= pd.concat([plh2_df,ny4_data], axis=1, sort=True)
```

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMqw8.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTEY3.png)

Comment: Data posted as text rather than an image is appreciated and please include a simple code snippet of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.concat` with `np.array_split`:

```
print(pd.concat(list(map(lambda x: x[:5], np.array_split(df, len(df) / 15))), ignore_index=True))
```

It should work now.

Comment: It reads the first 5 lines  for every 15 lines like it is supposed to until line 50 but it the begins to shift by one after that. So it reads the first 5 lines for every 16 lines